# Is there any way to send FB messenger notifications(chat bot) using firebase?

Tags: firebase, sendmessage, facebook-chatbot

We need the type of message in firebase that can Trigger a third-party API(Facebook chat bot service) in order to perform any task: send a letter, send message to FB messenger, etc.
We want to be able to configure this message type(message content, message link, chose the audience, URL where will send the POST request.) through the Firebase dashboard.

I think I find the way we can send messages to Fb messenger using Firebase and our own chatbot service.
Here is the article https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message 
But I can't understand how can we add our service URL to these requests.

Could you help me with that? Can someone share the experience of using Firebase to send FB messenger messages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to setup webhooks for triggering a call to your API. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions